# App navigation example using WidgetsApp

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to declare my apps navigation. As I am not using `MaterialApp` wrapper or styling, all my imports come from `package:flutter/widgets.dart`.

As per docs, to use Navigation properly I am doing this:

```
import "package:flutter/widgets.dart";
import "package:myapp/routes/home.dart";

void main() {
  runApp(
    new WidgetsApp(/* stuck here */);
  )
}
```

And I am stuck at this step, I am trying to follow [Navigator docs](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html) and code comments in ide, but I can't figure out how to use `onGenerateRoute` property of `WidgetsApp`, nor can find full example of this online, hence the question.

Similarly to `new MaterialApp()` how do I define my home path and rest of the routes within `new WidgetsApp()`?

As a follow up question to this, am I allowed to to use wildcard routes like `/onboarding/**` or `/dashboard/**` inside `new WidgetsApp()` somehow to route into layouts which then have switch statement checking for a route and display pages?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `onGenerateRoute` property to generate route for widgets app.

Here is a very minimal implementation of the same:

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyWidgetsApp());

class MyWidgetsApp extends StatelessWidget {

  Route generate(RouteSettings settings){
    Route page;
    switch(settings.name){
      case "/":
        page =  new PageRouteBuilder(
            pageBuilder: (BuildContext context,Animation<double> animation,
                Animation<double> secondaryAnimation){
              return new Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  const Text("Home Page",textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,),
                  const Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0)),
                  new GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/first"),
                    child: new Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      color:Colors.blue,
                      child: const Text("Go to First Page"),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0)),
                  new GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/abcd"),
                    child: new Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      color:Colors.blue,
                      child: const Text("Unkown Route"),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              );
            },
            transitionsBuilder: (_, Animation<double> animation, Animation<double> second, Widget child) {
              return new FadeTransition(
                opacity: animation,
                child: new FadeTransition(
                  opacity: new Tween<double>(begin: 1.0, end: 0.0).animate(second),
                  child: child,
                ),
              );
            }
        );
        break;
      case "/first":
        page =  new PageRouteBuilder(
            pageBuilder: (BuildContext context,Animation<double> animation,
                Animation<double> secondaryAnimation){
              return new Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    const Text("First Page",textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,),
                    const Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0)),
                    new GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                      child: new Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        color:Colors.blue,
                        child: const Text("Back"),
                      ),
                    )
                  ]
              );
            },
            transitionsBuilder: (_, Animation<double> animation, Animation<double> second, Widget child) {
              return new FadeTransition(
                opacity: animation,
                child: new FadeTransition(
                  opacity: new Tween<double>(begin: 1.0, end: 0.0).animate(second),
                  child: child,
                ),
              );
            }
        );
        break;
    }
    return page;
  }

  Route unKnownRoute(RouteSettings settings){
    return new PageRouteBuilder(
        pageBuilder: (BuildContext context,Animation<double> animation,
            Animation<double> secondaryAnimation){
          return new Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                const Text("First Page",textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,),
                const Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0)),
                new GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                  child: new Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    color:Colors.blue,
                    child: const Text("Back"),
                  ),
                )
              ]
          );
        }
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new WidgetsApp(
        onGenerateRoute: generate,
        onUnknownRoute: unKnownRoute,
        textStyle: const TextStyle(),
        initialRoute: "/",
        color: Colors.red
    );
  }
}
```

Hope that helped!

Comment: Oh wow, there is a lot to this compared to wrapping in MaterialApp. Thank you for the example, I'll go ahead and break it down. Meanwhile, I found good alternative in this library: https://github.com/goposse/fluro

Comment: Got your version implemented successfully, but having issues figuring out how to make route animate when it is replaced. I followed Navigator api docs and have that spin and fade transition working (https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html) Issue that I see now is that while new route is animating in, old one is visible until new one is finished. Ideally I would like to first fade rotate out old route, then fade rotate in new one.

Comment: The transition builder provides `secondaryAnimation` argument which you can use to achieve what you are trying to. [Here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/routes.dart#L665) is how you can implement it.

Comment: I shortly discovered it after posting my comment, but came across an issue with fade transitions. As per your example I used `FadeTransition` instead of `SlideTransition` and as its child nested another `Fade transition`. As these two are using `animation` and `secondaryAnimation` one will always be at 0 transparency, hence content will never be shown, any ideas of a work around?

Comment: I just updated my answer to implement `transitionsBuilder` into `PageRouteBuilder`. Hope this is what you were trying to achieve. The previous route fades out and then the new route appears and vice versa. Hope that helped!

Comment: Yep it does the trick, I was missing Tween, will need to read up on animation docs regarding this thank you. If you have time for a follow up: Right now they cross fade, is it possible to wait for fade out to finish (so wait until `animation` is done) before starting `second` animation?

Comment: You can just build your own `Tween` to achieve it.

Comment: Something like this

Comment: `class MyTween extends Tween<double>{
  double begin;
  double end;

  MyTween({this.begin, this.end}):super(begin:begin,end:end);

  @override
  double lerp(double t){
    final double val = begin + (end - begin) * t;
    return val<0.5?0.0:2*(val - 0.5);
  }
}`

Comment: I'll give this a shot, thanks, just for anyone who might come around to this, `lerp` is from `dart/ui` package