# How can i make a list and click on item to navigate to a new route

Tags: dart, flutter

I know this code only displays title and i want to make a onTap method to navigate to a new route, but this is how fare i made it, any help, hint, tip, even shaming me for how stupid i am would be very much appreciated.
Edit: I did posted the whole code because something is going wrong even after help that i got here. maybe is a syntax problem or maybe i am just too stupid

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Scaffold(
  body: new ListView.builder(
    itemCount: data == null ? 0 : 10,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
      return new Card(
        child: new ListTile(
            onTap: _onTapped,
            title : new Text(data[index]["title"]),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
);
```

}
}

Comment: Just a little bit of research : https://flutter.io/routing-and-navigation/
https://flutter.io/gestures/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App navigation example using WidgetsApp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48024504/app-navigation-example-using-widgetsapp)

Comment: It's surprising that in early 2020, the Flutter Cookbook still doesn't contain an example of this common navigation pattern, which is sometimes call "menu list  navigation".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just wrap your title in a `GestureDecector` to handle clicks.
Then call `Navigator`'s `pushNamed` to redirect to a new route.

```
new GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, "myRoute");
  },
  child: new Text("my Title"),
);
```

Comment: been trying since you comment it but still, one problem leads to another, anyway i appreciate your help and i will keep trying

Comment: If that does not solve your problem, please explain why. If it does, mark the answer as correct for future users. If another problem popped feel free to ask another question.

Comment: After i added the gesture detector and on tap **Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.**

Comment: Are you sure you used the correct syntax ? `onTap: function, child: widget` ?

Comment: i edited my post, can you take a look now the whole thing what is wrong

Answer (score 1):

An easier approach I found is to just wrap the item inside the ListTile with a FlatButton (or some interactive widget). In your code, for example:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new ListView.builder(
        itemCount: data == null ? 0 : 10,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
          return new Card(
            child: new ListTile(
              title: FlatButton(
                child: new Text(data[index]["title"]),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => YourPage()),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
```

Comment: I like the GestureDetector in the chosen answer.  It's simpler.  It doesn't introduce another component, the FlatButton.