# How to navigate to a specific route in a list full of the same widget?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

I have a an app which the user is able to add in books and it upload to the firestore database, and then I use a `streamBuilder()` to recieve all the data and display it in a list of `GestureDetector()` with the `card()` as a child.

Here is the code for the

```
final bookWidget = GestureDetector(
                          key: ValueKey(loggedInUser.email),
                          onTap: () {
                            print(title);
                          },
                          child: Card(
                            semanticContainer: true,
                            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                            child: Stack(
                              children: [
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Container(
                                      width: 100,
                                      height: 140,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                        image: DecorationImage(
                                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                            image: NetworkImage(bookCoverURL)),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      width: 230,
                                      //color: Colors.red,
                                      child: Column(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                        crossAxisAlignment:
                                            CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                        children: [
                                          Text(
                                            category.toString(),
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.grey,
                                              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          Container(
                                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                                            child: Text(
                                              title.toString(),
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                fontSize: 17,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          Container(
                                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                                            child: Text(
                                              (author),
                                              style:
                                                  TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Icon(
                                      Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      size: 15,
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            //color: Colors.yellowAccent,
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                            ),
                            elevation: 5,
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          ),
                        );

                        bookWidgets.add(bookWidget);
```

And then I display all my code in the screen by :

```
  Column(
   children: bookWidgets,
  )
```

[image: The image]

But how can I make the app navigate to a new screen when the user pressed on a specific `card()`? Since all of them are the same widget and have no unique identifier?

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     GestureDetector(
                      key: ValueKey(loggedInUser.email),
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.pushNamed(
                        context,
                        '/routeNameHere',
                        arguments: id,
                        );
                      },
                    )
```

In parameter arguments: ID - you can change the id by the id of the card that you want to navigate to.

You must create a page for the display detail of the card, which just displays a card with same id in the argument. So on your new page, create a variable for receiving the argument, e.g.:

```
final cardId = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as String;
```

So the page can display the card depending on the cardId.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I do not have ID for each card ( it only have name, author, owner(the logged in email), and pages). Do I need to make one ID field for the book object?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create an identifier to pass (in this case “book”). In Flutter, these are necessary when calling or passing an object.

However, in regards to using [Named Routes](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments) , this can allow you to send the data without the identifier but is considered bad practice in coding as you would not have a reference to the call or be able to back trace through the data.

Keeping the above in mind, [it is possible to use the OnTap() inside each child card container](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48030789/15803365) so that on handle clicks or tap gestures, the user is taken to a different screen using routes as it is part of the GestureDetector class.